# How to recognize the meaning of a linked list function in c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I'm currently stuck on some functions operating on single linked lists made with a struct in c++.

I am supposed to find out what do these functions do without compiling, but I cannot seem to have understood the theory behind it completely, since my guesses are all to generic.

Is there a way to guess the reason behind these function's existence just by looking at them? And what do they do?

Also, what will happen if I call q(la, lb) if la=(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6) and lb=(3, 4, 5)?

```
bool u(List l, int x) {
  if (l=nullptr) return false;
  if (l->info == x) return true;
  return u(l->next, x);
}

void v(List& l, int x) {
  List tmp = new (cell);
  tmp->info = x;
  tmp -> next = l;
  l = tmp;
}

List q(List l1, List l2) {
  List aux = nullptr;
  while (l1!=nullptr) {
    if (!u(l2,l1->info)) v(aux,l1->info);
    l1=l1->next;
  }
  return aux;
}
```

Comment: Of course there's a way not just "to guess the reason behind these function's existence just by looking at them", but to determine it conclusively. This is done by reading each function's code, analyzing it, and determining what the function does. For example, if the only thing that the function contains is `a=b;` you can proudly conclude that the function's purpose is to assign `b` to `a`. Similarly, by looking at each function's code, one can easily determine what it does. All of these functions are basic linked list operations, and are not very complicated.

Comment: `u` will always crash as it sets `l` to `nullptr` and promptly dereferences it.

Comment: You might try drawing the lists out on scratch paper or a whiteboard, then trace through the code. Note that `u` uses recursion to traverse the list. `q` uses iteration instead, and it uses both `u` and `v`. Once you understand what those functions do, understanding `q` should be pretty simple.

Comment: @Botje: Quite right. I think that is clearly intended to be `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a reasonable guess as to what these functions could do from just the declarations.

```
bool (List, int)
```

Takes a list and an element and returns a true/false answer. An immediate guess is "does this list contain this element". We then look at the definition (*), see that the null list is false, the list starting with `x` is true, and otherwise we look at the tail for the answer. Thus our guess was correct.

```
void (List&, int)
```

Takes a list reference, and an element, and returns nothing. An immediate guess is that it adds an element to a list somewhere. Looking at it's definition, we see that a new node is allocated, and initialised as an element and made to be the head of the modified list. Again, our guess helped identify exactly what it does.

```
List (List, List)
```

Takes two lists and returns a list. An immediate guess is that it joins the two lists together. And we see that it basically does this, but only adds values from the second list that are not present in the first.

(*) and fix the undefined behaviour of assigning `nullptr` to `u` rather than comparing it.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
bool u(List l, int x)
```

checks if list `l` contains value `x` in field `info`. The function

```
void v(List& l, int x)
```

appends the value `x` to the list `l`. The function

```
List q(List l1, List l2)
```

checks for each value in list `l1` if it is also an element of list `l2`. If the value is element of list `l2`, the value is appended to list `aux`. The list `aux` is returned.

There are some errors in the code. The line

```
if (l=nullptr) return false;
```

does not compare but assign. `aux` is a pointer to the last element of the list and not to the head.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was not "what are these functions doing?", but "how to recognize what they are doing?"

Comment: More than that, this is a bad question, and bad questions should not be rewarded with answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first function

```
bool u(List l, int x) {
    if (l == nullptr) return false;  // corrected: it should be '==' not '='
    if (l->info == x) return true;
    return u(l->next, x);
}
```

The key is to understand the likely type of `List`. From experience with linked lists and from the code, it appears that we have something like

```
struct Node
{
    Node*next;
    int  info;
};

typedef Node *List;
```

Thus, `u()` takes a `List l` and a value `x`. If the list headed by `l` is empty (`l==nullptr`), it returns `false`. Otherwise, it the node info equals `x` it returns `true`. Otherwise, it calls itself recursively with `l` replaced by `l->next`.

Thus, `u(l,x)` will returns true if and only if at least one of the nodes in the linked list contains the value `x` as `info`. A more suitable name for this function would have been `contains()` with the simpler implementation

```
bool contains(List l, int x)
{
    return l && (l->info==x || contains(l->next,x));
}
```

You can use this same logic now to find the meaning of the other functions.